# Javascript prevent file download by direct url

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to prevent file download from website by direct URL.

This way I need to allow file download only when a some custom parameter is set along with a client request.

Is it possible via JavaScript to set for example custom HTTP request header value when user clicks the HTML link for file download ? Based on presence of this parameter server side logic will decide - allow file download or no.

If it is not possible what other approaches can be used in order to prevent file download by direct URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, your question is "Can I add a custom header to a request using Javascript?".

If you are using ajax to do your request, it's pretty simple. Here's an example:

```
// Request with custom header
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar',
    headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});
```